# Localizing a date from a recordset in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

In an attempt to better serve a Canadian customer, we are trying to localize the dates displayed on some old classic ASP pages. We've started to use the SetLocale() vb script function with some success -- correctly handling user input dates.

However, I expected a date returned in a ADODB.Recordset to respect the page's locale. Consider the following code:

```
SetLocale 4105

'''
' Get a list of Employees
SQL = "SELECT Firstname, Lastname, HireDate FROM Employee"
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open Application("ConnectionString")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandText = SQL
Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.CursorLocation = 3
Set rst = cmd.Execute
```

When writing the column *HireDate* out to the page, it is rendered as MM/DD/YYYY (the format used by our servers).

A few things to note:

1. We need to serve both US and Canadian customers on the same server (so changing the server's localization/region is not an option). This has to be a pure code solution.
2. I noticed that the *TypeName* of *rst("HireDate")* is "Field" -- not Date as I would have expected.

What is the proper way to localize the date values coming from SQL server in this scenario?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you saying that despite `SetLocale 4105` the format of the date is not as expected?  BTW use `TypeName(rst("HireDate").Value)` what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may still need to use the FormatDateTime function to get it to display properly.

Try

```
FormatDateTime(rst("HireDate").Value, vbShortDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

rst("HireDate") is a Field

rst("HireDate").Value will be a Date

rst("HireDate").Value.ToString(), will return the date as string in the locale of the machine the statement is executed on, almost certainly the machine IIS is running on which may or may not be the box sql server is ruuning on.

Look up GetLocale/SetLocale uis one way, another is to rely on client side jaavscript to display dates as strings.

Comment: Its sooo easy it mix up .NET code with when doing retro stuff isn't it?   There is no .ToString() method (or indeed any methods what so ever) on primitive types in VBScript.

Comment: I did VBScript once..... Format? Cstr? Either way I figured he was talking server side.